# PHP exec with JQ - [] brackets error: PHP Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading

Tags: php, command-line, jq

I have the following command within a PHP script:

```
shell_exec('cd /home/scripts/scripts; ./total.sh | jq '.hits .hits [] .fields["termListData.terms"] | .[]' | wc -l > /home/data/total.csv');
```

which gives me: PHP Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading ...

the command alone from the command line works perfect but not when within the php script. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You probably need to have the entire command as a string.

Comment: @Carcigenicate - thank you. Could you give me an example? I tried a few things to put it into a string but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have single quote in your command execution

you can probably split your command in two

```
$jq_args = '.hits .hits [] .fields["termListData.terms"] | .[]';
$cmd = 'cd /home/scripts/scripts; ./total.sh | jq '.escapeshellarg($jq_args).' | wc -l > /home/data/total.csv';
shell_exec($cmd);
```